# Python module decide what should be imported an what not inside module file, when importing the module to another file

Tags: python, python-module

module example file:

```
mode = "add"

def ab(a, b):
    if(mode == "add"):
        return a + b
    else:
        return a - b
```

If I now import the module like this in my main.py file:

```
import module.py as calc
```

the mode variable gets imported aswell. How can I declare what should be imported and what not inside the module.py file?

Comment: Are you talking about in the import line like `from module.py import ab as calc`. I’m not sure if this is what you’re asking for and if it would solve the `mode` issue, but thought I would try!

Comment: First of all, if `mode` is meant to be a read-only constant, then by convention it really should be capitalized, i.e. `MODE`. But why is this even an issue for you? Is it because you are concerned that it can now be modified as in `calc.mode = some_value`?

Comment: @Jarvis I think `from module.py import ab` would make more sense as `calc` was meant to alias the module not the function within it. And what if the module in reality contains multiple functions (not shown) that now need to be selectively imported to avoid importing the unwanted `mode` variable? You wouldn't then randomly be choosing one of those functions to be assigned the alias `calc` in that case.

Comment: I only added the `as calc` since he has it in his question.